# How i implement test rspec for controller admin trestle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, trestle-admin

I create the controller copy syllabus in trestle in:

```
app/admin/copy_syllabus.rb
```

This is my content

```
Trestle.admin(:copy_syllabus) do
   menu do
     item :copy_syllabus, icon: "fa fa-tachometer"
   end

   controller do
     def index

     end

     def create
     end
  end
```

So I need to add rspec test for this controller

I tried with this structure of files

```
rspec/admin/copy_syllabus_controller.rb
```

But when I run:

```
rspec spec
```

show me the error

```
NameError:
  uninitialized constant Admin::CopySyllabusController
```

Comment: Use a [request spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) instead of a controller spec. Request specs drive the whole stack and are more future proof.

Comment: Thanks for response, So how i implement login test in request with trestle?. Do you have a example?